# npm ERR! code E404 when running command npm i --save core-js zone.js rxjs system.js

Tags: angular, visual-studio, npm

I am trying to use visual studio for angular 6.
I am getting errors 
npm ERR! code E404 and
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: system.js@latest when inputting the command npm i --save core-js zone.js rxjs system.js

the full log is as in the image [image]

can anyone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Change `system.js` to `systemjs`:

```
npm i --save core-js zone.js rxjs systemjs
```